# How to strip out the url

Tags: php, preg-replace

Hey guys, can you tell me how to strip out the website and leave only the page visited?

My code:

```
$url = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', parse_url($url['url'], PHP_URL_HOST));
```

Does: `http://domain.com` or `http://www.domain.com`

I need it to give me only what's after it.

Example: `index.php`, or `index.php?setlang=en`

Thanks in advance.

### Edit:

Here is the code I am currently using to get the URLS:

```
//Pagina
$from = $_GET['pagina'];
if( !empty($from) )
{
    $from = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', parse_url($from, PHP_URL_PATH));
}    

$url = $DB->fetch(
        "SELECT url FROM {$CONF['sql_prefix']}_sites WHERE username = '{$username}'",
        __FILE__,
        __LINE__
        );

$url = preg_replace( '/^www\./', parse_url( $url['url'], PHP_URL_PATH ) );
if( !empty ($from ) && $from != $url )
{
    insert('pagina', $from);
}
```

Comment: I replaced HOST with PATH and still gives the full link. can i post the code?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `parse_url` already; how about reusing it?

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$url = $path . ($query ? '?' . $query : '');
```

Comment: `parse_url` with `PHP_URL_PATH` already returns a starting `/`. Your code will return `//index.php?foo=bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the `parse_url` function to use `PHP_URL_HOST`, which will ALWAYS return the part you don't want.

I've never used this function, but perhaps try:

```
$tmp = parse_url($url['url']);
$url = $tmp['path'] . "?" . $tmp['query'] . "#" . $tmp['fragment'];
```

instead, which should return the chunk that you want, *without any regex*.

From the docs: [parse-url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: You are missing ? between path and query.

Comment: true, and the '#' between query and fragment.  Updated

Comment: i can't use this cause the pages are inserted into the db from websites that are registered on mine

Comment: @RaTza ?  Could you reword that?  I don't understand.

Comment: the path is the pages that are visited  on the websites that are registered on mine.Those paths are isnerted into my database and are shown  to the members registered.

Comment: here is my code: //Pagina
$from = $_GET['pagina']; if(!empty($from));
$url = $DB->fetch("SELECT url FROM {$CONF['sql_prefix']}_sites WHERE username = '{$username}'", __FILE__, __LINE__);
$url = preg_replace('/^www\./', parse_url($url['url'], PHP_URL_PATH));
if(!empty($from) && $from != $url) insert('pagina', $from);

Comment: You should post that code in your question so everyone can benefit and use the built-in methods to format it.

Comment: Even after your update, I still don't understand why my solution wouldn't work.  Could you give an example of how your site is used?

Answer (score 0):

You're already using `parse_url` so you can use this array to get your information:

```
$parsed_url = parse_url($url['url']);
$path = $parsed_url['path'].(isset($parsed_url['query']) ? '?'.$parsed_url['query'] : '');
```

Comment: //Page visits
$from = $_GET['pagevisit']; if(!empty($from)) $from = preg_replace('/^www\./', '', parse_url($from, PHP_URL_PATH));;
$url = $DB->fetch("SELECT url FROM {$CONF['sql_prefix']}_sites WHERE username = '{$username}'", __FILE__, __LINE__);
$url = preg_replace('/^www\./', parse_url($url['url'], PHP_URL_PATH));
if(!empty($from) && $from != $url) insert('pagevisit', $from);